# How to put text on top of a tabular in display math?

Tags: tables

How do I get the x and y to be on top of the tabular? Instead of being on the side.

```
\begin{displaymath}
        x = 2, \ y = 4 
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            [-1, & 3, & 1] \\
             &  &  $\uparrow$ \\
            \end{tabular}
\end{displaymath}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

By use of `gather` math environment (defined in the `amsmath` package):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
    x = 2, \ y = 4          \\
\begin{array}{ccc}
    [-1, & 3, & 1]          \\
         &    &  \uparrow
    \end{array}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank u this works!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `gathered` inside `equation*` (that's the same as `displaymath`).

You can also fix the alignment of the up arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{gathered}
x=2,\ y=4 \\
\begin{array}{@{}r@{} ccc @{}l@{}}
[ & -1 & 3 & 1 & ] \\
  &    &   & \uparrow
\end{array}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `@{}` we declare that there's no intercolumn space between columns (or padding around the `array`).

Comment: thank u this also works!